# how web applications communicate each other in struts?

Tags: struts

I have two web applications in web application server. i want to get data from one application to another. how do i do in Struts. i know that it is possible by webservices. But, is there anyway that i could get it using struts?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use query string to pass data using request parameters.

```
/action.do?varA=1&var2=3
```

This'll work for simple cases. For complex requirements/exchange please use Web Services or other integration technologies.

Comment: then i should get response data back to this application.how do i get it?